# JInput->get() , how does it work?

Tags: development, joomla-api, jinput

I'm a beginner in Joomla and a little confused with this method.

for example consider this : `$app->input->get('foo',0,'int');`

where is the source of `foo` ?

`JInput->get()` get's inputs from where ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Source of `foo` are the [PHP superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) such as $_POST or $_GET. So it's data what the user submits via a form, URL or cookie to your component.

So you are receiving in a safe way a parameter that was sent to you via a HTTP method.

This:

```
$myVar = $app->input->get('foo',0,'int');
```

is largely equivalent to:

```
$myVar = (int) $_REQUEST['foo'];
```

You should always use [JInput](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput), no matter what. You just forget about the PHP superglobals. Read the whole documentation in silence, you should know it by heart.

Comment: To avoid any warning, it's better to check if `$_REQUEST['foo']` is set: `$myVar = isset($_REQUEST['foo'] ? (int) $_REQUEST['foo'] : 0;`

Comment: What warning? The code with request is just an example, not something to use.

Comment: Yes, my comment is about a general PHP rule to avoid PHP warnings and not a Joomla one. I wanted to say that `$myVar = $app->input->get('foo',0,'int');` is equivalent to `$myVar = isset($_REQUEST['foo'] ? (int) $_REQUEST['foo'] : 0;`.